# JScrollPane "jumping" when scrollbars start being used

Tags: java, swing, viewport, point

Sorry, this is a long piece of sample code below, but here's the issue:

I have a background that I'm actively drawing (I could probably be smart and draw it once and just scale it, but this shows the problem just as well).

You can use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out on the image.

The idea is to do a "google map" zoom where it zooms under the mouse pointer. What I've noticed is that it doesn't seem to actuall behave until the image is big enough to use both scroll bars. Until then, you get the image simply getting bigger, but locked to the origin.

The "correct" behavior should be that the viewposition is moved, even though the scrollbars aren't yet being utilized by an oversized image.

I'm not sure how to get around this (or if this is correct and expected) without drawing a much larger background behind the image so it more than fills the viewport.

It "jumps" after one or the other scroll bars engages due to (I think) the same issue.

Thoughts?

```
package com.hostigr.raw.io.client.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
            new TestFrame();
    }

    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

        add(new TopPanel());

    }

    private class TopPanel extends JPanel {
        JScrollPane scrollPane;

        public TopPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new InteriorPanel());
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
            scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,490));
            scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(490,10));
            scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(false);
            scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            add(scrollPane);

        }
    }

    private class InteriorPanel extends JPanel {
        private double scale = 10.0;
        private final double scaleModifier = 0.1;
        private final int width = 10;
        private Point loc = new Point(0,0);
        private final int SIZE = 10;

        public InteriorPanel() {
            super(true);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(scale * width * SIZE),
                    (int)(scale * width * SIZE)));
            this.addMouseWheelListener(new MapMouseWheelListener());
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2D.scale(scale,scale);

            for (int row = 0; row <= SIZE; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
                    if ((col + row) % 2 == 0) {
                        g2D.setColor(Color.white);
                    } else {
                        g2D.setColor(Color.black);
                    }
                    g2D.fillRect(col * width, row * width, width, width);
                }
            }

        }

        private void incrementScale(int notches) {
            double modifier = 0;
            double prevScale = scale;
            if (notches != 0) {
                modifier = 1.0 + -notches / Math.abs(notches) * scaleModifier;
            }
            scale = scale * Math.pow(modifier, Math.abs(notches));
            /*if (scale * width < 1) {
                scale = 1.0/width;
            } else if (scale * width * 3 > parentHeight || scale * width * 3 > parentWidth) {
                if (parentHeight > parentWidth) {
                    scale = parentWidth / 3.0 / width;
                } else {
                    scale = parentHeight / 3.0 / width;
                }
            } else if (scale * width * SIZE < parentWidth) {
                scale = parentWidth / (double)SIZE / width;
            } else if (scale * width * SIZE < parentHeight) {
                scale = parentHeight / (double)SIZE / width;
            }*/

            this.repaint();
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(scale * width * SIZE),
                    (int)(scale * width * SIZE)));

            JViewport viewport = ((JViewport)(getParent().getParent().getComponent(0)));
            Point orig = viewport.getViewPosition();
            viewport.setViewPosition(new Point(
                    orig.x - (int)Math.round(loc.x*(1 - scale/prevScale)),
                    orig.y - (int)Math.round(loc.y*(1 - scale/prevScale))));
            System.out.println(orig + "\n  " + loc + "\n  " + (1 - scale / prevScale));
            revalidate();
        }

        private class MapMouseWheelListener implements MouseWheelListener {

            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                loc = e.getPoint();
                incrementScale(e.getWheelRotation());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I realized a way to articulate the issue: The viewport is setting a viewable rectangle /within/ the component that is in the scrollpanel. If the component is smaller than the viewable rectangle, obviously that paradigm doesn't make any sense. HOWEVER, I feel that you should /still/ be able to shift the position of the interior component relative to the viewable rectangle somehow? Or is my only answer to draw an opaque border that's larger than the viewport so it stays "larger" than the scrollpane?

Comment: Oh, and even when I limit the minimum size so that it's equal to the size of the viewport, there is still a discontinuity that happens ... a small "jump" in the zoom step /after/ the scrollbars engage, and I'm not sure what causes that.

Comment: sorry I can't see any of update by your side, don't move with JViewPort if contains Rectangle or Point,

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

looks like as `JViewPort#scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle r)` for me works

```
     viewport.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(new Point(
     orig.x - (int) Math.round(loc.x * (1 - scale / prevScale)),
     orig.y - (int) Math.round(loc.y * (1 - scale / prevScale)))));
```

EDIT and with correct Swing repaint's rulles, then yout codeBlock must ends with `revalidate(); +  repaint();`

```
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (scale * width * SIZE), 
        (int) (scale * width * SIZE)));
        JViewport viewport = ((JViewport) (getParent().getParent().getComponent(0)));
        Point orig = viewport.getViewPosition();
        /*viewport.setViewPosition(new Point(
                orig.x - (int) Math.round(loc.x * (1 - scale / prevScale)),
                orig.y - (int) Math.round(loc.y * (1 - scale / prevScale))));*/
        viewport.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(new Point(
                orig.x - (int) Math.round(loc.x * (1 - scale / prevScale)),
                orig.y - (int) Math.round(loc.y * (1 - scale / prevScale)))));
        System.out.println(orig + "\n  " + loc + "\n  " + (1 - scale / prevScale));

        revalidate();
        repaint();
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing something, but this doesn't display the correct behavior. My goal is a zoom functionality like google maps, where the point you have at the mouse doesn't move. With this, the viewport tries to keep the "shifted origin" in view, which it almost always should be anyway. So you get a zoom, but like the corner of the panel is attached to the corner of the scrollpane. In the original, the behavior was correct /after/ you zoom in far enough.

Comment: yes, your Point is somewhere on the JViewPort, but you you have to calculate with Scrollable increnent/decrement (in pixels), then you able to scrolling to this area, and not sure if this code centered your point in Visible JViewPort, because scroolToVisibleRectangle  move Point to the Left-Top corner

Comment: Updated original post with comment for clarification. I think the issue is the concept of a viewable rectangle within the scrollpane that contains a container smaller than the rectangle, but I'm still not sure what a "good" resolution to that problem will be.